# Making negate work after character-class with MySql Rexep

Tags: mysql, regex-negation

I am trying to capture records with specific terms followed by digits. I used both:

```
Select * from Table where Field Regexp 'Term [0-9]{1,6}'
```

and

```
Select * from Table where Field Regex 'Term [[:digit:]]'
```

However the issue is I grab ordinal #s like:

`Term 33rd` and `Term 19th`

which I don't want. I only want `Term 33` and `Term 19`

I tried both:

```
Select * from Table where Field Regexp 'Term [0-9]{1,4}[^a-z]'
```

and

```
Select * from Table where Field Regex 'Term [[:digit:]][^a-z]'
```

Neither of which has any affect. Yet if I do

```
Select * from Table where Field Regex 'Term 33[^a-z]'
```

It will reject `Term 33rd` but find `Term 33`.

So it recognizes the `[^a-z]` negation when not using  character class, leading me to believe there is some additional construction required to get the `character-class` and the `regex negation` to co-exist.

Comment: Add $ sign for end of line : 'Term [0-9]{1,6}$'

Comment: @BerndBuffen It isnt' the end of line that is breaking it not to mention the term can continue past the end of line. It works fine w/o $ w/o negation and works fine w/o $ using explicit digit and negation. So it is clearly some combination of character-class followed by negation.